# Discard response data from libcurl

Tags: c, file, pointers, libcurl

Libcurl defaults to stdout when handling a server's response. We can override it with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`. From the manual I got that I could set the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` to `NULL` and then pass a `FILE *` to `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`. If I just want to not use it what would be the most efficient way to go about it?

Specifically, if you need to provide a `FILE *` to a function, but you want it to be discarded how would you go about it?

Also, as I'm writing this I realised that maybe I shouldn't pass `NULL` to `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, and instead write a function which does nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write to [`/dev/null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) or a similar black hole. Note that the existence and location of such special file(s) is OS dependent - Unixen have /dev/null, Windows has \Device\Null, etc.

Comment: So what would be an OS independent solution? An empty write function?